# kubernetes cluster on raspberry pi 4- coredns problem

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I'm having problems getting a kubernetes cluster setup on raspberry pi 4.

I'm unable to get internet access from inside the pods

I'm trying to use [flannel](https://github.com/coreos/flannel)

I have the same setup working on a raspberry pi 3, without problems so I don't think there's anything wrong with my network.

The problem appears to be with **coredns,** the logs show the following:

```
pi@rpi4-reg:~ $ kubectl -n kube-system logs coredns-6955765f44-wvsz4
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 4e235fcc3696966e76816bcd9034ebc7
CoreDNS-1.6.5
linux/arm, go1.13.4, c2fd1b2
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:41212->4.2.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:33647->192.168.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:33755->4.2.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:55151->192.168.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:50820->4.2.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:56227->192.168.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:48078->192.168.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:52120->192.168.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:48378->192.168.2.1:53: i/o timeout
[ERROR] plugin/errors: 2 1228749791.1011458686. HINFO: read udp 10.244.0.3:59986->192.168.2.1:53: i/o timeout
```

The coredns config file

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  Corefile: |
    .:53 {
        errors
        health {
           lameduck 5s
        }
        ready
        kubernetes cluster.local in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa {
           pods insecure
           fallthrough in-addr.arpa ip6.arpa
           ttl 30
        }
        prometheus :9153
        forward . /etc/resolv.conf
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
    }
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-17T08:26:29Z"
  name: coredns
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "188"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/coredns
  uid: 287d7906-f126-4fd3-8937-b98cf9ea8833
```

resolv.conf

```
nameserver 4.2.2.1
nameserver 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Are you able to ping to 8.8.8.8? You can use a [busybox](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/testdata/recursive/pod/pod/busybox.yaml) to test running: `kubectl exec -it busybox ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: No, it doesn't find 8.8.8.8 

`kubectl exec -it busybox1 ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
85 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
command terminated with exit code 1`

Comment: Try to execute this command: `sysctl net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1`. Please tell me if that works.

Comment: tried that, but no changes. I've tried recreating flannel and coredns pods too, still the same

Comment: Did you check if you have some iptables rule in your OS? Or tried to chance to calico to see if the CNI is the problem?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was struggling with this for almost 2 days, and the issue was using different CIDRs in flannel compared to what I used in `kubeadm init`.

For `kubeadm init` I used CIDR `10.0.0.0/16` and for `flannel` I used the default `10.244.0.0/16`. Below are the details and commands I used;

```
# Initializing kubeadm
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.1.31 --pod-network-cidr=10.0.0.0/16
# Installing flannel using default config
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

Checking the `kube-flannel-cfg` config map, I noticed that CIDR is different from the `kubeadm init` as below.

```
net-conf.json: |
{
  "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
  "Backend": {
    "Type": "vxlan"
  }
}
```

So, the solution was to update the config map CIDR network to match the one you used while initializing the Kubernetes cluster.

Don't forget to delete all the `flannel` pods to get the new config.

```
kubectl delete pods -l app=flannel -n kube-system
```

---

Useful debugging steps. I installed DNS Utils for debugging DNS in Kubernetes as referenced [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/).

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml
```

After deploying the DNS utils you can first lookup google to check whether you have an issue in the DNS itself or flannel network.

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup google.com
```

If DNS looked up google correctly then you move on with debugging your network configurations (it can be CIDRs like me, `iptables`, firewall, or something else)

```
kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- ping google.com -c 4
```